# how to make collection of list from dict having same id?

Tags: python-3.x

```
[{'id': 6, 'name': 'Jorge'}, {'id': 6, 'name': 'Matthews'}, {'id': 6, 'name': 'Matthews'}, {'id': 7, 'name': 'Christine'}, {'id': 7, 'name': 'Smith'}, {'id': 7, 'name': 'Chris'}]
```

And i wanna make collection of list having same id like this

```
[{'id': 6, 'name': ['Jorge','Matthews','Matthews']}, {'id': 7, 'name': ['Christine','Smith','Chris']}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
L = [{'id': 6, 'name': 'Jorge'}, {'id': 6, 'name': 'Matthews'}, {'id': 6, 'name': 'Matthews'}, {'id': 7, 'name': 'Christine'}, {'id': 7, 'name': 'Smith'}, {'id': 7, 'name': 'Chris'}]


temp = {}
for d in L:
    if d['id'] not in temp:
        temp[d['id']] = []
    temp[d['id']].append(d['name'])

answer = []
for k in sorted(temp):
    answer.append({'id':k, 'name':temp[k]})
```

Comment: just use `.setdefault` or even a `defaultdict` instead of `if d['id'] not in temp:`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.groupby` to group all the `id`s and then just extract the `name` for each element in the group:

```
In [1]:
import itertools as it
import operator as op

L = [{'id': 6, 'name': 'Jorge'}, ...]

_id = op.itemgetter('id')
[{'id':k, 'name':[e['name'] for e in g]} for k, g in it.groupby(sorted(L, key=_id), key=_id)]

Out[1]:
[{'id': 6, 'name': ['Jorge', 'Matthews', 'Matthews']}, 
 {'id': 7, 'name': ['Christine', 'Smith', 'Chris']}]
```

Comment: `groupby` will not work consistently here, unless the list is ordered by dictionary key...

Comment: True, added sorting. Can't assume the data is sorted, though the example from the OP was sorted. Which may or may not make it too expensive to use.